# Adding a Item to a ListView to a specific Column

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I need exactly this: [Click Me](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1255635/880472)

But just for WPF.

And I know, that I should use Binding etc. , but its just for a own test.

I didn't find out yet how I can achieve that..

Comment: Binding is (can be) really simple. Why do you want to avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this:
Yes I know this attempt uses a concrete object *Person* and binding, but using this approach, it is really simple just to modify the columns/properties you need without taking care of the ListView itself. I think that an approach *with* binding is more simple than any other.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="FirstName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="LastName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}"></GridViewColumn>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      ObservableCollection<Person> list = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

      list.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Firstname", LastName = "Lastname"});

      DataContext = list;

    }
  }

  public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 

    private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName {
      get
      {
        return _firstName;
      }
      set
      {
        _firstName = value;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
          PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FirstName"));
        }
      }
    }

    private string _lastName;
    public string LastName 
    {
      get
      {
        return _lastName;
      }
      set
      {
        _lastName = value;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
          PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LastName"));
        }
      }
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

In WPF when changing items you almost always do the changes in your bound data and notify the UI about these changes.
So you have to utilize *ObservableCollection* and implement *INotifyPropertyChanged*.

Please do not try to solve WPF issues like you did in WinForms, you will get stuck at some point as the architecture and the programming style is totally different...

**XAML:**

```
  <Grid>
    <StackPanel>
      <ListView x:Name="MyListView">
        <ListView.View>
          <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="City" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding City}"/>
          </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
      </ListView>
      <Button Height="50" Click="Button_Click">Click</Button>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
```

**CodeBehind:**

```
private ObservableCollection<MyData> _data;

public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();

   _data = new ObservableCollection<MyData>()
                                        {
                                          new MyData() {City = "City1", Name = "Name1"},
                                          new MyData() {City = "City2", Name = "Name2"},
                                          new MyData() {City = "City3", Name = "Name3"},
                                        };
  MyListView.ItemsSource = _data;
}

public class MyData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private string _name;

  public string Name
  {
    get { return _name; }
    set { 
      _name = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("Name");
    }
  }

  private string _city;

  public string City
  {
    get { return _city; }
    set
    {
      _city = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("City");
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
  {
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
  }
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  _data[1].City = "NewValue";
}
```